# How to find all dangerous permissions which have been used on lower version in the Android Project

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

The current targetSdkVersion is 21, but I want to update it to 23. So I need to know all the API which need dangerous permissions. The amount of source code is huge. I cannot check code line by line.

eg: The permission of CAMERA; I need to take a pic in the app.

Is there a good idea could search the API in the source code?

Comment: @NileshRathod I think the question is not duplicate since he wants to find out which API needs dangerous permission rather than, which permissions fall in dangerous category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

1. Go to settings and ensure Lint for missing permissions is enabled.

   [image: Lint]
2. Then go to `Analyze -> Run inspection by name -> Enter Missing permission` and press enter. This will list all the places where you are using the APIs and proper permission check is required. Alternatively you can press `Ctrl+Alt+I`:
   [image: missing permission]

   **Choose appropriate Scope**
   [image: Scope]

   **The errors will be shown at bottom as follows:**

   [image: lint error]

   Double click on line to view specific line of code.
3. Once you have identified those, check out your Manifest file too and check if you are using any of the [dangerous permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Which AS studio version are you using?

Comment: I was wrong and the result is 0 files processed. The version is 3.1.3. I don't know why 0 files.

Comment: You need to choose proper project dir while scanning

Comment: Great! It works! I just used file name filter '.java' ,It didn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about the permissions then check the manifest file. you can find permissions there

Comment: When I update the targetsdkversion to 23,I need to check dangerous permissions by code not write statements in manifest. So the most important is to know the api that need dangerous permissions.